# Is it possible to convert Firewire signal to Ethernet TCP/IP signal?

Tags: firewire

Currently the device is connected via Firewire800 (1394b) to Mac System. However, The bundled software detect the ip 10.xx.xx.xx through the FW800 connection.

Since the FW800 connectors have been disappeared, is there any easy way to convert 1394b signal in middle and just provide same signal through ethernet cable?

Currently the FW800 signal is generated from the machine side, converted to optic one through firewire-optical converter. Then, the optic signal re-converted using same converter to FW800 and connected to Mac, and finally provides the FW-ethernet connection to the machine. I think this converting chain is not very efficient.

Is there any way to improve in user side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s hard to tell without more information about the “device”, the “bundled software” and the reason why you are using firewire-optical converters.

The device might have an ethernet port next to the firewire port. Then it should be trivial to connect it to the computer through its ethernet port. I guess this is not the case.

There is a standard for IPv4 over firewire ([RFC2734](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2734)). Your device and bundled software are probably using this standard. But the vendor might also have implemented their own private IPv4 (or a subset of it) over firewire protocol. In that case, then you probably have no other choice than use a firewire connection between the computer and the device. It might also be using other firewire-based communication besides its IPv4 over firewire.

Even if it uses standard IPv4 over firewire, the bundled software might restrict to binding to the firewire interface. In that case, you are out of luck. It might also scan all network interfaces for the device, or let you choose a network interface to use.

If the device is only using standard IPv4 over firewire and the bundled software is able to use the device through an ethernet-based network, then it should be possible to use an intermediate device between the device and the computer that hosts the bundled software. It would be firewire-connected to the device, and ethernet (any flavor you like) connecter to the computer, and act as a pseudo-bridge between both networks. Then you probably can install that intermediate device close to the device and avoid the firewire-optical conversion.

I don’t know any dedicated device that implements that but it might exist. Otherwise, you probably can implement such a device with any computer that has both a firewire and an ethernet port. You would have to do some low-level networking configuration on that intermediate device like enable routing, ARP proxying and possibly some NATting.

My suggestions are:

- ask the vendor,
- check the manuals for the device and the bundled software,
- investigate the configuration options of the bundled software,
- if you are brave enough, try implementing an ethernet-firewire pseudo-bridge on a computer.